# Error in expo start "Error: Problems validating fields in app.json."

Tags: android, json, expo, apk

**Error: Problems validating fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/
• should NOT have additional property 'adaptiveIcon'.
• should NOT have additional property 'permissions'.
• should NOT have additional property 'versionCode'.
• Field: android - should NOT have additional property 'googleMobileAdsAppId'.
• Field: android.config - should NOT have additional property 'googleServicesFile'.**
i get this error when i type **expo start**

```js
  "expo": {
    "name": "xx",
    "slug": "xx",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scheme": "xx",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-document-picker",
        {
          "appleTeamId": "NHHHUJTTT",
          "iCloudContainerEnvironment": "Production"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./assets/icon96x96.png",
          "color": "#5675",
          "mode": "production"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-ads-admob",
        {
          "userTrackingPermission": "wants to track you to collect IDFA to deliver personalised ads."
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-tracking-transparency",
        {
          "userTrackingPermission": "wants to track you to collect IDFA to deliver personalised ads."
        }
      ]
    ],
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#F723",
      "resizeMode": "cover"
    },
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/icon96x96.png",
      "color": "#F2320",
      "iosDisplayInForeground": true,
      "androidMode": "default"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "usesAppleSignIn": true,
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.XXxX",
      "buildNumber": "1",
      "usesIcloudStorage": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Your App Name uses the camera to capture and upload user profile image and Listing Image to the server.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Your App Name needs access to the photo library to select and upload user profile image and Listing Image to the server.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "Your App Name needs access to the photo library to select and upload user profile image and Listing Image to the server.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Your App Name usages device location on listing information, Listing search Data and User information.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Your App Name usages device location on listing information, Listing search Data and User information.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "Your App Name uses device location on listing information, Listing search Data and User information.",
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "Your App Name uses your microphone while taking video of your product for uploading in listing information.",
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true,
        "UIBackgroundModes": [
          "remote-notification"
        ],
        "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription": " wants to track you to collect IDFA to deliver personalised ads.",
        "SKAdNetworkItems": [
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork"
          }
        ]
      },
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "mjo8@#$%^&*(NYH87HNYB87B87"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.adfars",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "mjo8H878ON7o7YN78NY####NYB87B87"
        },
        "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
      },
      "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-######~2444070320"
    },
    "adaptiveIcon": {
      "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#fff"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "CAMERA",
      "CAMERA_ROLL",
      "MEDIA_LIBRARY",
      "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
      "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
      "RECORD_AUDIO",
      "READ_PHONE_STATE",
      "READ_CONTACTS",
      "LOCATION",
      "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
      "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
      "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
    ],
    "versionCode": 17,
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "########-48e8-9250-b8fe859b188b"
      }
    }
  },
  "facebookScheme": "fb87867657656546545",
  "facebookAppId": "87867657656546545",
  "facebookDisplayName": "Your facebook app name",
  "scheme": "com.xxxx"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

These options are in the wrong settings sections, you can download the [Expo Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=byCedric.vscode-expo) extension to have autocomplete.

The correct config is something like this:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "xx",
    "slug": "xx",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scheme": "xx",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-document-picker",
        {
          "appleTeamId": "NHHHUJTTT",
          "iCloudContainerEnvironment": "Production"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./assets/icon96x96.png",
          "color": "#5675",
          "mode": "production"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-ads-admob",
        {
          "userTrackingPermission": "wants to track you to collect IDFA to deliver personalised ads."
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-tracking-transparency",
        {
          "userTrackingPermission": "wants to track you to collect IDFA to deliver personalised ads."
        }
      ]
    ],
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#F723",
      "resizeMode": "cover"
    },
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/icon96x96.png",
      "color": "#F2320",
      "iosDisplayInForeground": true,
      "androidMode": "default"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "usesAppleSignIn": true,
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.XXxX",
      "buildNumber": "1",
      "usesIcloudStorage": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Your App Name uses the camera to capture and upload user profile image and Listing Image to the server.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Your App Name needs access to the photo library to select and upload user profile image and Listing Image to the server.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "Your App Name needs access to the photo library to select and upload user profile image and Listing Image to the server.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Your App Name usages device location on listing information, Listing search Data and User information.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Your App Name usages device location on listing information, Listing search Data and User information.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "Your App Name uses device location on listing information, Listing search Data and User information.",
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "Your App Name uses your microphone while taking video of your product for uploading in listing information.",
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true,
        "UIBackgroundModes": [
          "remote-notification"
        ],
        "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription": " wants to track you to collect IDFA to deliver personalised ads.",
        "SKAdNetworkItems": [
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork"
          }
        ]
      },
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "mjo8@#$%^&*(NYH87HNYB87B87"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.adfars",
      "versionCode": 17,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#fff"
      },
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "mjo8H878ON7o7YN78NY####NYB87B87"
        },
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-######~2444070320"
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "CAMERA_ROLL",
        "MEDIA_LIBRARY",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "RECORD_AUDIO",
        "READ_PHONE_STATE",
        "READ_CONTACTS",
        "LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
      ]
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "########-48e8-9250-b8fe859b188b"
      }
    },
    "facebookScheme": "fb87867657656546545",
    "facebookAppId": "87867657656546545",
    "facebookDisplayName": "Your facebook app name"
  }
}
```